# "Among the flavors" or "from the flavors" or "of the flavors"

Tags: prepositions

I have a question about the preposition you can use when you are choosing something from a group of things.

When you are talking about the time when someone went to an ice cream parlor and had to choose from many flavors, which sentence can you use?

> **Among** the flavors available at the store, mint and pecan looked good
> to him.
>
> **From** the flavors available at the store, mint and pecan looked good to
> him.
>
> **Of** the flavors available at the store, mint and pecan looked good to
> him.

Comment: They're all fine. Don't waste your time and energy trying to identify the "best" preposition. Idiomatically, it seems at least *feasible* to me that ***Out of all** the flavours available at the store...* might actually be more common than all your suggestions - but no-one would notice anything particularly good or bad about your choice of phrasing, whichever you used.

Comment: "Among", "of", "out of" are all perfectly natural. "From" works well if paired with "choose", but in isolation is a bit odd or may lead to a different interpretation.